# How is the SQL Server Folder "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\" organized?

Tags: sql-server, sql

In `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\`, I'm seeing many sub folders such as

- 80
- 90
- 100
- MSAS10_50.MSSQLSERVER
- MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER
- MSSQL10.50.MSSQLSERVER

What are these sub directories for?
Are they for each SQL Server instance?
Can we delete the folders?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063872/find-what-sql-versions-installed-by-folders

Comment: Do not delete those folders until you've spoken very carefully to your DBA, and only then you'll have to remove instances and features to be able to remove them. If you need space, look elsewhere. If SQL was installed with defaults, speak to a DBA to move the database files to another drive if you need the space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those folders are for different SQL Server components.

The MSAS folder is for SQL Server Analysis Services

The MSRS folder is for SQL Server Reporting Services

The MSSQL folder is for the SQL Server Database Service (database engine)

I don't believe the folders are created unless you've installed those compnents, so I'd recommend not deleting them.